# Updating Search Results for Dynamically Generated Web Pages

Tags: google, search-engines, asp

Having an issue with search results finding the proper site, but the wrong year.

The page itself is dynamically generated based on get requests in the URL.  There are three identifying properties.

MemberID
Year
Part (1 or 2, first or second half of the year)

Each part of the year, a new committee is formed.  Even if a member remains from a previous committee, their ID does not necessarily remain the same in the database.

Here is the issue.  Let's say John Smith is the member, and has been a member for two years (4 parts).  When I search John Smith, google shows results for his first year:

`MemberInfo.asp?memberID=20&year=2012&part=1`

However, I want that result to be the most recent year.

`MemberInfo.asp?memberID=39&year=2014&part=2`

The old information must still be accessible as people will need to view what issue John Smith dealt with during that particular year, so the data can't be made inaccessible.

What is the best way to address this?  I'm not even sure where to start.  Thanks.

Comment: Just an update, I've currently added some code that adds `<link rel="canonical" href="MOST_RECENT_URL" />` to all the old pages, and pointing it towards the most recent year.  Hopefully this forces the bots to treat them as identical pages, and only lists the newest as the search result.  I have to wait for the site to get recrawled to test, but will report back with the results.

Comment: I'm not sure why your member ids are changing.    It seems like keeping the member id the same would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @Stephen - I'm not sure why the database was set up that way to be honest.  It is an aspect that i have no control over.  Multiple internal applications rely on the same database, so it's extremely unlikely that the format will change.  The best I could do would be to add another field with a flag of some sort to indicate whether it is the most current entry for a member, or what that URL would be.

Comment: Is there something in the database that uniquely indentifies a memeber and lists each "memberID" for that member?